# Opening Idle with a python script

Tags: python, windows, python-idle

I'm a windows user, and currently I have a simple script to launch all the programs I need while writing code.

Its called setup.py. This is just two programs that it opens...

```
import sys, string, os
os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application")
os.startfile(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
os.chdir(r"C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib")
os.startfile(r"C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.py")
```

When I run this program a shell window pops up, both Chrome and Idle launch, however the shell window stays open

When I exit the shell window (*To make room in my task bar*) Idle closes and chrome stays open. I would like both to stay open.

How can I do this?

**EDIT** 
This probably has to do with the extension type `.exe` vs `.py`.. still not sure how to go about this though

Not sure if the windows tag is relevant,. ask me to remove it and I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's the extension type. `startfile` operates like double-clicking a file in Windows explorer, so if you navigate to a Python file (.py) and double-click it, it launches the file and the console. If you want just the file, change it to:

```
os.startfile(r"C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw")
```